# Insert PHP date into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to insert a date field from a form into a mysql database. If the user does not input a date, the current date should be used.  My code is :

```
if ($_POST[date]==0)
    {$ref_date=date('Y-d-m');}
    else {$ref_date=$_POST[date];}

$L="insert into referral (ID,patient, Doctor,Date) values (default,$pat,$doc,'$ref_date')";
        mysql_query($L) or die(mysql_error());
```

It works fine when I submit a date in the form, but when I leave that field blank it inputs 0000-00-00.

Comment: You code contains SQL injections! NEVER USE VARIABLE IN SQL STATMENTS. If you need parameter in statements, use prepare statements and/or parameter!

Comment: Your right.  I am actually switching to a form of pdo, but since I wasn't sure where the bug was I wrote the query like this to confirm that the problem wasn't in my implementation, and then I thought that if I posted it like this everyone would understand the query rather than my needing to explain all my functions.
Using mysql_query I can echo back my function and test it directly in MySQL to find the bug.  Is there any way to do something similar using parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL expects dates to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You have `YYYY-DD-MM`. Change:

```
$ref_date=date('Y-d-m');
```

to:

```
$ref_date=date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention, though, that Apache's (or whatever php server you're using) may have a different time/timezone compared to your MySQL server.

Let's say Apache's server is 2h ahead of MySQL. If it's 1 am of January 22 (in Apache), then using date('Ỹ-m-d') would return 2015-01-22, and CURDATE() (MySQL current date's function) would return 2015-01-21.

So, there are 2 possible solutions. One is John Conde's solution:

```
$ref_date = date('Y-d-m');
```

The other would be insert CURDATE():

```
$ref_date = 'CURDATE()';
```

Comment: so $ref_date would become the string "CURDATE()", but MySQL would understand that to mean the MySQL function?

Comment: That's right. Besides, I highly recommend you not to pass the parameters as string. Use something more secure like Prepared Statements

Comment: So how could I find out what the timezone(s) of the server is?  I am using a host who provided me with both a server for my web pages and a MySQL database.

Comment: Well, these information are editable in the configuration files (php.ini for PHP and my.cnf for MySQL, if I'm not mistaken). To know if they are the same, you can echo the full time (date, hours, timezone) in a php page (the function date(...) is the same, but the parameters change. For mysql, you can run phpmyadmin page (or mysql -u <username> to acess via terminal) and run "select *, now() from <table>;"